# ssh - Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

Tags: ssh, remote

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1

If I want to remote connect by **ssh** to UNIX machine (Ubuntu) from my local machine (Windows 10) I do the next step:

1. Run `cmd`
2. Execute the next command

   ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no mwallet@192.168.210.16

Prompt password and as result I success connect to remote machine.

Here screenshot:

[image]

OK. Nice.

Now I want to do same on Emacs.
So my steps:

1. `M-x shell`
2. Execute command

   ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no mwallet@192.168.210.16

But I get error:

**Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.**

Here screenshot:
[image]

Comment: `M-x shell` provides a dumb terminal, which isn't sufficient for Emacs. There's `M-x term` and `M-x ansi-term` which should be sufficient, but I doubt they would work on windows.

Comment: I don't know Microsoft's ssh implementation, but usually you can call `ssh -t -t ...` in order to get a pseudoterminal. Yes, `-t` twice.

Comment: I try `M-x term` or `M-x ansi-term` , Emacs in minibuffer `"Run program D:/Programs/emacs/libexec/emacs/25.1/x86_64-w64-mingw32/cmdproxy.exe"` , press Enter ---> result error: `Spawning child process: Invalid argument.`

Comment: Well, it looks like Microsoft ssh does not support this ...

Comment: By Tramp mode I success connect to remote Unix machine. So, this is a one decision?

Comment: Yes, with Tramp you'll connect to a remote UNIX or whatever machine, which runs the sshd daemon. However, I haven't tried it with local MS ssh. I've used PuTTY under MS Windows.